# git gc and git pull locks up machine and never finishes

Tags: git, git-pull, git-gc

When running `git gc`, git gets up to 99% complete and then locks up.  I let it run all night and it never finished, and did not seem to progress.  Generally I have to hard-reset the machine to recover because everything locks up.  Because the machine becomes completely unresponsive I can't get `top` or `htop` statistics.

I decided to ignore that problem for awhile.  Today however, when running a `git pull`, git decided to auto pack the repository, which triggered this same error.

This is where it gets stuck:

```
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
Counting objects: 428464, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects:  99% (93702/93718)
```

This is a Qt 4.8 C++ project on Fedora 17.  I have 8GB of RAM and the partition holding the project is 33G with 27G used (88% full).

What could be causing this problem?  If the machine lacks resources for running `git gc`, is there a way to tell git not to auto pack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

If you skip all the generated binaries and the dlls and heavy things in the repository then it shouldn't have a problem with optimization.

Here is how you disable it:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: if I skip using all the git then it shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seven years later I am getting the same problem on Debian. This behaviour does seem somewhat sub-optimal.

Workaround: even if the desktop is locked, I can still get to a virtual console (`Alt-Ctrl-F1`) and log in as root and `pkill git` to unlock everything.